# Is this JavaScript code wrong?

Tags: javascript

In this [JavaScript lesson](http://www.codecademy.com/courses/javascript-beginner-en-ASGIv/2/3) on Codecademy it is required to write a do/while loop, I have written this, and it passes

```
var getToDaChoppa = function(b){
  var a = b;
  do{
    console.log("Dunno!");
    } while (a < b);

};

getToDaChoppa(25);
```

But when looking closely at my code, I think that I may have done it completely wrong since `a` has no defined value?

Or since the variable of `b` is local inside the function, it does not affect the `b` argument which is passed a value of 25?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes it is wrong since nothing modifies either a or b

Comment: Since `a = b` and neither is modified later, `a < b` will always be false. The body of your loop will only run once.

Comment: Which is why it passes since they wanted you to pass the loop only once

Comment: the code can be wrong or not depending on what you expect from it, it compiles, that's an start

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It simply does only one iteration, because when the `do while` `loop` starts, the condition is not satisfied because `a` and `b` are equals. So

```
var getToDaChoppa = function(b){
  var a = b;
  do{
    console.log("Dunno!");
    } while (a < b); //25 < 25, exit 

};

getToDaChoppa(25);
```

If you want to try a `do` `while` loop try with some trick like

```
var getToDaChoppa = function(b){
  var a = 10; //or whatever minor than b 
  do{
    console.log("Dunno!");
    a++; //when it reaches 25 or whatever value you set it breaks the loop
    } while (a < b);

};
```

This is just an example to let you figure out how `do while` works

Answer (score 3):

The code's fine, the logic's wrong. You are assigning `a` the value of `b`, so they'll be always equal.

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning the value of `b` to `a` with the statement `var a = b;`

The loop will run once since you are using a do while loop.

The code is not wrong, it is designed to illustrate that the condition is evaluated after the first iteration of the loop.

http://jsfiddle.net/puleos/QXC9z/

Answer (score 0):

> Is this JavaScript code wrong?

depends on what problem you wanted to solve.

It looks pretty useless to me since the body of the loop will always be executed once.

`while (a < b);`will always return `false` because of `var a = b;` and `a` is not modified in the loop.

Comment: a < b will always be false, not true

Comment: yes... my brain was twisted because of the awesome method-name

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're after is:

```
var getToDaChoppa = function(b){
  var a = 0;
  do{
    console.log("Dunno!");
    a++;
  } while (a < b);

};
```

As mentioned by other posters, if `a = b` the loop will only run once. This version should run the expected number of times (if that truly is what's expected).

Answer (score 0):

Since the question says "Your loop should print a string of your choice to the editor one time", I think this is correct.  Your code will print the string "Dunno!" exactly one time.

However the `a` and `b` variables and the `do..while` loop might as well not exist at all, they are only adding unnecessary complexity to the code which could be simplified to one line (the `console.log()` call).